# How to change column value corresponding to change in another column?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Hiii,,
i am using c# and dev express.In my project there is a layoutview and i need the column values of some columns to change corresponding to the change in a single column....please help me

Comment: Could you give any further information or sample code? Which set of DevExpress controls - WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: haii daniel,it is for winforms.....i will explain the scenario..consider there is three columns name them as 'state', 'pincode','country',If am changing the value of the column 'country' then the other two column should show null....help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the LayoutView's CellValueChanged event to catch the moment when a value is changed and change other column values.  this can be done using the LayoutView.SetRowCellValue method.